# Rewrite rule ignore what's in front

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to rewrite

> http://www.example.com/a/b/c/d/S123

with endless virtual subdirectories (keywords) to

> http://www.example.com/?id=123

But it seems my rule is only working for

> http://www.example.com/S123 (without "subdirectories").

What is wrong on this rule?

```
^S(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$
```

Comment: anyone? I don't find the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^S... means that your url segment STARTS with S which is true for /S123 and not for a/b/a/S123.

use this regex instead :

```
^.*S(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$
```

Comment: That is strange. try this ^\.*S(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$

Comment: :(  this might me related to escaping . try this? ^.*S(?:.+/)?(\d+)/?$

Comment: THANK YOU! Are you an alien? I mean, how can anyone ever understand regex... it's just inhuman ;)